# Asynchronous updating / AJAX in Django 1.4

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

Hi I am still new to Django and have not worked with Ajax before.

I am building an app where two players are able to chat, so it's basically a chatbox and I want the page to update for one player when the other player enters text on their page. I was wondering if anyone had any good resources for this type of functionality?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try html5 websocket.

For JavaScript and ajax, refresh the page at a timed interval. Or better fetch new messages via an ajax call and append to the DOM.